# Get VMPeak After Process Termination

Tags: linux, process, pid

I need `VMPeak` in `/proc` about one child process **after termination**.

But `wait()` released all resource, so I will get: "No such file or directory"

I'd be grateful if you could help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. The /proc/{pid}/status file for the process is deleted after termination of the process. So you can not extract the VMPeak.